# Method that will be executed before every Route method call in ASPNET Core MVC WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

Is there a way to define method that will be executed before every Route method call.

```
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    private static int i;

    private void funcToCall()
    {
        i++;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Ping()
    {
        return Ok("Pong")
    }
}
```

I want to call funcToCall whenever Ping Route is called. I also cannot do it in constructor, because lifetime of controller is Singleton.

I was wondering if overriding [HttpGet], [HttpPost] etc... attributes will work, but I also belive it may be simpler solution.

Comment: Have a look into mvc filters, should let do what you are after https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Filters as mentioned above will let you "intercept" MVC actions (the filter lets you see the controller/action being invoked and then decide to redirect or abort etc).

If you wanted to you could also write your own middleware and ensure this is added to the pipeline prior to the MVC routing stuff, though this is more complex and you'd only have the "raw" request info, not controller/action stuff.

Also, Controllers are *not* by default singleton, but have request scope - in your case here you happen to have a `static` field which will be shared by all instances, but its not a singleton.

Comment: Additionally... your example is extremely basic and you *could* just call the method from your action method - it would help if you could explain what you are trying to actually achieve, and why simply calling the method like this is not desirable.